# Ruby Mail duplicated search

Tags: ruby, email, imap

I am using the ruby Mail gem, which uses Net::IMAP internally to search within a mailbox. 
I am searching through a series of different folders within the mailbox. 
At times there is a duplication in the messages. Two messages with the same message_id. 
In addition to this, when querying a particular mailbox, another message from a different mailbox will be added in. 
Bare in mind this is a massive mailbox, with thousands of messages.

As for the code that does the search is extremely basic. It uses the default find and passes in the mailbox.

Is there a way to prevent this? Is this an indexing issue? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mailboxes can contain duplicated mail. It happens quite often, e.g. when someone sends mail to developers@example.com, uxdesigners@example.com and someone is on both teams.

It's just a fact of life. Deal with it.

Regarding your other problem, IMAP servers never ever return messages in other mailboxes as part of a search result. That's not syntactically possible. Here's a search command and response to illustrate:

```
a uid search from <arnt@example.com>
* search 123 234 345 456 567 678 789
a OK search completed
```

Even if the server by mistake confuses its indexes and *means* to include message 678 from some other mailbox, the client will consider message 678 in *this* mailbox as matching the search, because that's the only way to interpret the response.

Comment: Thanks for this. However the search is duplicated against folders within the same mailbox, not different mailboxes. @arnt, any idea on this?

Comment: What you call folders is called "mailbox" in the documents, so for "mailbox" in my answer, read "folder".